# Get option value in combobox and textarea receive this value to copy

Tags: javascript, combobox, html-select

I'm a JavaScript beginner, I want to get the option's value but in my current code I'm getting its text content.

Example of what I need:

- User selects option "Blue" -> textarea receives value "sky is blue". Then on button click "sky is blue" is copied to clipboard.
- User selects option "Black" -> textarea receives value "I like this color". Then on button click "I like this color" is copied to clipboard.

The same for the other color.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.2.js">
</script>

</head>

<body>

<select>
<option value="Sky is blue">Blue</option>
<option value="I like this color">Black</option>
<option value="Color of my car">Red</option>
</select>

<textarea type="text" class="js-copytextarea"></textarea><button class="js-textareacopybtn" style="vertical-align:top;">COPY</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.js-textareacopybtn');

copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('.js-copytextarea');
  copyTextarea.focus();
  copyTextarea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
});
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$('body').on('change', 'select', function() {
$('textarea').val($(this).find(":selected").text()).select();
})
//]]></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already using vanilla JS for a large part of your code, you don't need jQuery for this.

You can add an event listener to the `select` element and get the value of the selected option on `change`. You can update the `textarea`'s value and then `select()` its content:

```js
select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  textarea.value = e.target.value;
  textarea.select();
});
```

Check out the snippet below for a working example:

```js
let copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.js-textareacopybtn');
let select = document.querySelector('select');
let textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  let copyTextarea = document.querySelector('.js-copytextarea');
  copyTextarea.focus();
  copyTextarea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
});

select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  textarea.value = e.target.value;
  textarea.select();
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="">Choose a color</option>
  <option value="Sky is blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="I like this color">Black</option>
  <option value="Color of my car">Red</option>
</select>

<textarea type="text" class="js-copytextarea"></textarea>
<button class="js-textareacopybtn">COPY</button>
```

Comment: Zsolt Meszaros, thank you so much. Your answer helped me learn event listener !

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If it is useful for you, could you please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)? It may help more people who have similar issue.